# cuda install error on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

```
   abigail@abilina:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cuda-repo-ubuntu1604.
(Reading database ... 205999 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1604 (8.0.61-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1604 (8.0.61-1) ...
Warning: The postinst maintainerscript of the package cuda-repo-ubuntu1604
Warning: seems to use apt-key (provided by apt) without depending on gnupg or gnupg2.
Warning: This will BREAK in the future and should be fixed by the package maintainer(s).
Note: Check first if apt-key functionality is needed at all - it probably isn't!
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package cuda-repo-ubuntu1604)
OK

abigail@abilina:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My ubuntu version is 17.04. Does this mean my Linux currently can't install CUDA? I want to install TensorFlow with GPU support.

Per suggestion:

```
abigail@abilina:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: CUDA 8 doesn't support  Ubuntu 17, which you would know if you bother to read the [release notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4fjBDgJ8J). This question is completely off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it as such

Comment: Looks like cuda 8 is supported : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/amd64/nvidia-cuda-toolkit it says 8.0.44-3 in the column version, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/amd64/nvidia-cuda-toolkit

above is the correct one.

`apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

but remember the cuda installed through apt were installed in different location. manually create `ln -s` at `/usr/local/cuda` for `include`,`lib64`,and `bin`

Comment: Is there an easy way to know which of the files belong to cuda to create these symbolic links? It seems to put the cuda files in the general bin include and lib paths... Also, is there a way to get the CUDA sample files?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe you can just unzip the bundle from nvidia cuda download page to get the sample. and also use `dpkg -L package-name` to get installed location for that (could be a long list)

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully installed CUDA 8.0 + the latest patch from NVIDIA on Ubuntu 17.04:

1. Download the .run file from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads, choosing Ubuntu 16.04 (Base Installer)
2. You will not be able to install it by just running, because it is looking for a file called InstallUtils.pm which is not present in Ubuntu 17.04, but curiously, is present in the .run file - so: unpack the .run file using `./cuda*.run --tar mxvf`
3. copy InstallUtils.pm (should be in the /bin path) to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
4. Run the installer (You may want to say no to the driver install step to keep the one you install through apt - I'm using 381.22, because 375.26, which is provided by the .run file does not support my 1080ti)
5. gcc 6 is incompatible with CUDA, but this is easily remedied for compiling the sample files: just add `export EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS="-Xcompiler -std=c++98"` to your bashrc file, and comment out

from one of the headers (I think it was host_config.h, but you'll see it once you try to compile) - comment out these lines:

```
#if __GNUC__ > 5 || (__GNUC__ == 5 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 3)
     #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5.3 are not supported!
```

This is all from memory, so hopefully it's accurate enough.

I managed to find this solution thanks to these useful posts:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/983777/can-t-locate-installutils-pm-in-inc/

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/949770/cuda-8-0rc-supporting-gcc6-/

Comment: you may need to do `sudo chmod a+x cuda*` first before doing `--tar`

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 17.04, I had to use cuda 9.0 (deb version)
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-release-candidate-download

I couldn't get it to work otherwise. Cuda 8.0 needs gcc 5.3.1 but cuda 9.0 is compatible with gcc 6.3.0 which is installed on ubuntu 17.04 automatically.

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, this is what I did:

On Ubuntu 17.04, install CUDA 9.0 — you can currently download the beta version 
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-release-candidate-download

I downloaded the .deb file and haven’t had any problems — follow the steps they recommend when you download cuda 9.0

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-0-local-rc_9.0.103-1_amd64.deb`

`sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9.0-local-rc/7fa2af80.pub`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install cuda`

Then follow the post installation steps from the nvidia instructions (i.e., setting PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 
 http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

`export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64                        ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`

Cuda 9 is compatible with gcc 6.3.0 (which comes with 17.04). I used arch=sm_52 and sometimes for my make files have to go ‘make clean’.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Cuda 9.0 was the simplest solution in my case.

Alternatively, if you'd prefer cuda 8, you can download the deb file and then use the command

`dpkg-deb -x cuda_8.*.deb /usr/local/cuda-8.0`

to extract the contents from the deb file and have them placed in the desired directory.

Source: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#advanced-setup)